# What are the security issues and race conditions in using `find -exec`?

Tags: shell, find, security

From the [`find` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

> ```
> -exec command ;
>     There are unavoidable security problems
>     surrounding use of the -exec action; you should use the
>     -execdir option instead.
>
> -execdir command {} +
>     Like -exec, but the specified command is run from the
>     subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not
>     normally the directory in which you started find.  This a much
>     more secure method for invoking commands, as it avoids race
>     conditions during resolution of the paths to the matched
>     files.
> ```

What does this mean? Why are there race conditions with running it from the starting directory? And how are these security risks?

Comment: Related: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) where that is covered in some of the answers.

Answer (score 16):

Found the details [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Race-Conditions-with-_002dexec.html):

> The `-exec` action causes another program to be run. It passes to the
>   program the name of the file which is being considered at the time.
>   The invoked program will typically then perform some action on that
>   file. Once again, there is a race condition which can be exploited
>   here. We shall take as a specific example the command
>
> ```
>  find /tmp -path /tmp/umsp/passwd -exec /bin/rm
> ```
>
> In this simple example, we are identifying just one file to be deleted and invoking
>   `/bin/rm` to delete it. A problem exists because there is a time gap
>   between the point where find decides that it needs to process the
>   `-exec` action and the point where the `/bin/rm` command actually issues
>   the unlink() system call to delete the file from the filesystem.
>   Within this time period, an attacker can rename the `/tmp/umsp`
>   directory, replacing it with a symbolic link to `/etc`. There is no way
>   for `/bin/rm` to determine that it is working on the same file that find
>   had in mind. Once the symbolic link is in place, the attacker has
>   persuaded find to cause the deletion of the `/etc/passwd` file, which is
>   not the effect intended by the command which was actually invoked.

Not sure how likely anyone could ever exploit this; but I guess there's the answer!

Comment: In the above case, `execdir` would first chdir to `/tmp/umsp` before running the command, and so theoretically, an attacker's relinking the directory would have no effect.. _if_ the relinking happened after find "decides" to evaluate `-exec` but before the `rm` command can do its work. But I wonder why this would make a difference: the attacker could simply do the relink after user has decided to write the `find` command.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro The link isn't the argument that's passed to the command, it's an intermediate directory. `/tmp/umsp` is a directory when `find` sees it, but when `rm` runs, the attacked has changed it to being a symbolic link to `/etc`. `/tmp/umsp/passwd` is a regular file all along, but not the same one.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the reason why `-exec` is dangerous is because if the user would not specify the full name and path to the program to be executed, it would potentially execute the wrong program.

Example:

```
find /some/path -exec coolprogram
```

In `/some/path`, someone made another `coolprogram`, and it uploads all your data to some bad actor.

But wait, you say, don't you have to execute it as `./coolprogram`? Yes, but some people have `PATH=.:/bin:whatever`, which will execute the program in the current directory.

This is probably simplified, but I think that it could be dangerous in some cases. I had to troubleshoot an issue once where a zero-byte `cpio` ended up in the wrong directory. It caused a program to crash because `cpio` did not work as it was running the zero-byte file in the directory.

Comment: These risks aren't isolated to `find -exec`. If you've put `.` in your path then simply executing `coolprogram` in your current dir is already dangerous, whether you use `find` to do it or not!

Comment: Agreed, but it seems that -execdir watches for the condition that I mentioned as well: `The ‘-execdir’ action refuses to do anything if the current directory is included in the $PATH environment variable. This is necessary because ‘-execdir’ runs programs in the same directory in which it finds files – in general, such a directory might be writable by untrusted users. For similar reasons, ‘-execdir’ does not allow ‘{}’ to appear in the name of the command to be run.`

Comment: I guess the moral of the story is that having . in your path is a bad idea also, which is why I make sure it isn't in there.

Comment: Interesting to know about disallowing `.` in path and `{}` in the command. Maybe in future Linux will just forbid `.` in path entirely and tools won't need to implement their own safety checks! :)

Comment: I think 90% of the code I write is only to catch the 5% of things that go wrong. :)