# Rename file names in multiple directories

Tags: files, rename

I have several directories with files out of sequence because the titles are displayed before the file number. I want to match and replace the end of all the files, minus the extension, so the number is at the beginning like so.

From this;

```
A guide to perfect eggs-456704.mp4
Boil an egg-456702.mp4
How to ruin scrambled eggs-456703.mp4
Make green eggs and ham-456701.mp4
Poached eggs-456705.mp4
```

To this:

```
456701-Make green eggs and ham.mp4
456702-Boil an egg.mp4
456703-How to ruin scrambled eggs.mp4
456704-A guide to perfect eggs.mp4
456705-Poached eggs.mp4
```

The titles are random in length for each file with spaces, the numbers are 6 digits before the ".mp4" extension but preceded by a dash after the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a way of doing this. It is untested

```
#!/bin/bash

files=(*file)

for f in "${files[@]}" 
  do 
     get_ext="${f##*.}"
     no_ext="${f%-*}"
     n="${f##*-}" nn="${n%.*}"
     mv "$f" "$nn-$no_ext.$get_ext"
 done
```

Comment: OP mentioned in multiple directories, so for each directories this script should be executed separately ?

Comment: @αғsнιη you are correct. I kinda wrote it in a hurry and didn't read the question properly. For multiple directories, your code is much better.  Your `find` might need a `-name '*.mp4'` otherwise files with `mp3` extension might also be moved.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) and [`Shell (Bash, ksh, ksh93, mksh, zsh) Pattern substitution expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```bsh
find * -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec bash -c 'echo mv -v "$1" "${1//[^0-9]}-${1//[\-0-9]}"' _ '{}' \;
```

- With `${1//[^0-9]}` we are removing everything except a number; The `//` is global replacement syntax while `/` is only for first occurrence of number.
- Then a dash/hyphe `-`, and with `${1//[\-0-9]}` we are removing everything which is a `-` or number (again assuming only one `-` and numerical part is there in files name).

We used `-exec` in above command which is not secure for some reasons<sup>[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/273965/72456), [2](https://askubuntu.com/q/621132/283843)</sup> and here because with Shell Substitution Expansion it will take file's path and cause unexpected rename + it will drop all dashes `-` in files name!

At the end don't forget to remove the `echo` above in commands to have actual rename where it used to dry run.

---

```sh
find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -execdir sh -c '
    n="${1##*-}";fn="${1%-*}"; 
    echo mv -v "$1" "${n%.*}-${fn##*/}.mp4" ' _ '{}' \;
```

Same as previous command but here we used [`shell (POSIX sh/bash/Korn/zsh) parameter substitution expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and this will grantee to keep all dashes `-` untouched within filesname if any like `a file-with -- here-006.file` except the last one which should be drop.

We are looking for the files only `-type f` ends with `.mp4` and with `-execdir` here, `find` is changing the current directory to the directory where a *file* found then execute the sh -c ' ... ' within that directory itself.

- With `n="${1##*-}"` "cut-up-to-last-prefix": we are removing everything from the begging of filename until last dash `-` seen and `-` itself and assign to variable `n`; The `$1` or `${1}` is the relative path to `./fileName` to the current directory by `-execdir sh -c '...' _ '{}' \;` returns.
- With `fn="${1%-*}"` "cut-up-to-first-suffix": We are removing everything from end of filename until first dash `-` seen and `-` itself and assign to variable `fn`.

  Now `n="456704.mp4"` and `nf="./A guide to perfect eggs"` (assuming for first file). Then;
- With `${n%.*}-` we are removing everything from end of fileName until first dot `.` seen and `.` itself and then added a dash `-`. So this will result only digits part of fileName `456704`.
- With `${fn##*/}.mp4` we are removing everything from begging of fileName until last slash `/` seen and `/` itself and then added `.mp4` at the end. So this will result `A guide to perfect eggs.mp4`.

  ---

<sup>1</sup> [What are the security issues and race conditions in using `find -exec`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/273965/72456)
<sup>2</sup> [Why using the '-execdir' action is insecure for directory which is in the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/q/621132/283843)

Answer (score 0):

```
set "a file blah blah-004.file" \
"b file blah blah blah-002.file" \
"c file blahh blah-003.file" \
"d file blah blah blah blabby blah-001.file" \
"e file blah-005.file"

for name; do
  old=$name                 # save old name
  ext=${name##*.}           # take extension
  name=${name%.*}           # remove extension
  number=${name##*-}        # take number
  name=${name%-*}           # remove number
  new="$number-$name.$ext"  # set new name
  echo mv "$old" "$new"     # test rename
done
```

Remove the last `echo`, if it works.

Comment: What if there were hundreds of files?

Comment: @αғsнιη What are you asking? How to remove the `set` in order to pass the names as arguments?

Comment: You are using `set` but this you will do for hundreds of files? this is not a way to add all files into the `set`.

Comment: Once again: remove the `set` and pass the list of names as arguments to the script. Either in the command line or by reading `stdin` using `xargs`. The use of `set` is just a mock-up for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative **find** + **prename** (*Perl* rename) solution:

```
find -type f -exec prename 's/^(.+?)([^\/]+)-([0-9]+)(\.[^.]+)$/$1$3-$2$4/' '{}' \;
```

Comment: @αғsнιη, if it's just for dashes - see my simple update

Comment: Another problem is that, this will fail if there is subdirectory including mp4 files together with `.mp4` files. I mean a directory with multiple mp4 files and a sub-directory also that it contains mp4 files as well

Comment: @αғsнιη, paraphrase your sentence, cause "subdirectory including files together with files" - sounds strange

Comment: a directory containing mp4 files and a sub-directory which that sub-directory also contains mp4 files (nested directories with mp4 files).

Answer (score 0):

This is a portable `sh` implementation.

```
find . -name "*[0-9].mp4" |
    sed "s/\(.*\/\)\(.*\)-\([0-9]*\)\.mp4/'\1\2-\3.mp4' '\1\3-\2.mp4'/" |
    xargs -p -L 1 mv -v
```

The `find` command is pretty straightforward: it will return only `.mp4` files that contain at least one digit before the extension.

The `sed` command duplicates the filename, sorrounding each filename with single quotes, and then the second filename gets the digit part moved between the relative file path and the filename accordingly (e.g., `'./a/Boil an egg-456707' './a/456707-Boil an egg.mp4'`).

The resulting list of current and new filenames are then passed to the `xargs` command, which will execute `mv -v`. The `-L 1` option is needed so that `xarg` processes one line at a time. You can remove the `-p` option from this command and change the options that `mv` should use.

I tested this implementation with your file list on Ubuntu `bash`, `sh`, and Mac OS High Sierra `bash` and `sh`, placing files in different subdirectories and adding a few files that didn't qualify.